# how to apply css position:absolute correctly?

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

the problem is div, called 'dragger_container' doen't behave as i expect, and gets out from the parent div. it is not acceptable, cause it's an element that shows user scroll progress (it's a jquery plugin mCustomScrollBar) and interacts with user.
ask anyone for help.
thanks in advance

ps
cannot attach screen cause of reputation, uploaded it here:
[screen_url](http://imageshack.us/f/651/60357048.jpg/)

```
.mcs_my_container
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.mcs_my_container .customScrollBox
{
margin-top: 10px;
position: relative;
height: 80%;
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
border: 1px solid green;
display: block;
}

.mcs_my_container .customScrollBox .container
{
position: absolute;
width: 70%;
top: 0;
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.mcs_my_container .customScrollBox .content
{
clear: both;
}

.mcs_my_container .dragger_container
{
position: absolute;
/*top: 10px !important;*/
width: 2px;
/*height: 50px;50px
height: 100%;*/
height: 110px;
top: 0px;
right: 20px;
float: right;
background: #000;
cursor: s-resize;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-khtml-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
cursor: s-resize;
}

.mcs_my_container .dragger
{
position: absolute;
width: 4px;
/*height: 100%;*/
height: 10px;/* !important;*/
background: #999;
text-align: center;
line-height: 10px;
color: #666;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-khtml-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
margin-left: -1px;
}

.mcs_my_container .dragger_pressed
{
position: absolute;
width: 6px;
margin-left: -2px;
height: 10px;
background: #999;
text-align: center;
line-height: 10px;
color: #666;
overflow: hidden;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-khtml-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
cursor: s-resize;
}

.divNoteText
{
position: static;
border: 1px solid red;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Just put your code here, http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: in case to have a syntax highlighting or to debug?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position: relative` to the parent container of `dragger_container` that you want it to be positioned within.

If you don't do this then `dragger_container` will be positioned absolutely to the nearest parent element that is relatively positioned, or if there isnt one then it will be positioned within `body`.